# Table top uneven stain

Tags: wood, staining

I am refinishing a table top. I started by using a wood stripper. Followed by sanding the entire table down with various grits. I then vacuumed the surface and used mineral spirits to prep for stain. I applied the stain and it came out very uneven. The ends of the table top did not take the stain the same as the rest of the table. To try and fix the issue I re-sanded the table top to the bare wood again and applied a wood conditioner. After the wood conditioner I reapplied the stain and got the same issue. As a last effort I switched to gel stain and it’s still inconsistent. I have never had an issue staining before. I don’t know what else to do here. [image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. Normally I'd ask you to indicate what research you did (externally and here) to try to solve the issue prior to asking the Question, but I'm voting to close as this is very similar to an existing Q&A here. FFR there are abundant guides to staining online and in finishing books, many of which address potential staining issues such as 'hold out' which this appears to be. Additionally at least some of them will cover a way to discover in advance if something like this seems likely to happen — by observing how the wood wets (with mineral spirits or another liquid).

Comment: I am closing this as a duplicate but welcome you to WSE.